# How to Increase Memory Frequency in Linux?

Tags: ram, bios

I have recently bought a pair of [Corsair DRAMs](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/xms3-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmx16gx3m2a1600c11) that should operate at 1600MHz, but are currently running at 1333MHz. I understand that the typical solution is to enable XMP from BIOS, but the problem is that my HP Compaq Pro 6300 has a limited BIOS and there is no such option. I have seen a software for Windows which allows users to set the parameters of memory manually ([MemSet](http://www.overclock.net/t/304459/memset)) though this has to be set on every reboot. I was wondering if there is a similar solution in Linux that allows me to use my RAM at 1600MHz.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specs on your Compaq model, 1600Mhz RAM is supported.  Your issue is most likely BIOs or mobo design related.

Looking at the manual for this machine, it seems that HP has a very narrow list of RAM that's supported.  Two, actually.  https://www.manualslib.com/manual/624149/Hp-Compaq-Pro-6300-Series-Microtower.html?page=42#manual

Another possibility is that the RAM you have is really 1333 Mhz and not 1600.

That said, it's unlikely that you'd notice any performance improvement for such a tiny bump in RAM speed.

As an aside, when installing new RAM, I always run memtest to verify speed, timing and error free operation.

Comment: It looks like HP has limited BIOS options and I don't see any options for adjusting memory frequency.

Comment: BTW, can you share a link to memtest? I see various results and some of them are not related to this discussion.

Comment: http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm